# pymssql - list of server connections instead of one connection

Tags: python, pymssql

I am using pymssql for my python project. (http://www.pymssql.org/)

I have many database servers which are replicated frequently and i would like to use all of them so if one of the server fails, pymssql can use other servers.

According to the pymssql docs you can put only one connection.

http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#functions

Is there a way to set more than one server?

At the moment I can only think of having a list of servers and loop through each one of them with try except block. - but that seems messy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So been looking around for many hours and I just decided to go with the try except list. Here is the code for our info.

```
@staticmethod
    def connect():
        servers = ["server1", "server2", "server3"]
        conn = None
        for server in servers:
            try:
                conn = pymssql.connect(server, settings.MSSQL_USERNAME, settings.MSSQL_PASSWORD, settings.MSSQL_DB_NAME, charset="ISO-8859-1")
                break
            except:
                logger.info("Failed to connect to MSSQL Server: " + server)

        if conn:
            return conn
        else:
            logger.info("Failed to connect to ALL MSSQL servers")
            return conn
```

If there is a better way please let me know! thanks.